# Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked: Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm trying to delete a database (from `Sql Server Management Studio`) and I receive this error:

> Transaction (Process ID 52) was deadlocked on lock resources with
>   another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I googled a lot (with a lot of result also here in so) but I cannot find any solution.

I really need to delete (and restore this db), but I'm stucked.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried it again?  Deadlock conditions are usually transient and usually will go away shortly after the deadlock is resolved.

Comment: Wait, you're trying to delete a DATABASE and got a deadlock?  Did you mean TABLE?

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer: No no, I mean DATABASE

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I tried a lot of times after some time

Comment: Have you tried setting the DB to single_user using `ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`?  That will boot all current connections to the DB.  Then follow that with `DROP DATABASE [DBName]`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have open transactions. For example, for the database `StackOverflow` I am opening a transaction like this:

```
USE StackOverflow
BEGIN TRAN
```

and

```
USE StackOverflow
exec sp_whoisactive
```

[image]

So, when I try to deleted it:

[image]

I get the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot drop database "StackOverflow" because it is currently in use.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3702)

If I choose `close existing connections` from the delete interface the database is successfully deleted.

Comment: Is what I thought, but as you see my error is not so clear :(